# Galois Correspondence

Tags: galois-theory

Let $f(x)=(x^3-2)(x^2+1)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Let $L$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I am trying to establish the correspondence between the subfields of $L$ and the subgroups of $G={\rm Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$.

I know that $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\ltimes S_3$. Thus the subgroups of $G$ are:

1. $C_2$
2. $S_3$
3. $C_3$ (three of them)
4. $C_2$ (as a subgroup of $S_3$)

On the other hand I know that $L$ has the following subfields:

1. $\mathbb{Q}$
2. $\mathbb{Q}(i)$
3. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$
4. $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$
5. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega)$

But I am not able to associate the subgroups and the subfields. Am I doing something wrong? OR have I missed something?

Thanks

-- Mike

Comment: $G$ is the direct product of $Z_2$ and $S_3$  (not the semi-direct product).

Comment: There are 3 subfields of degree 2  (the one you overlooked is generated by $\sqrt{3}$).  There is one subfield of degree 4 (generated by $i$ and $\sqrt{3}$).  There are 3 subfields of degree 3  (one for each of the three conjugates of $\sqrt[3]{2}$).  Then there are a bunch of degree 6 (one for each element of order 2, of which there are 7).

Comment: Thanks for the correction on the direct product.!

Comment: Where does $\sqrt{3}$ come in from? Do you mean $\sqrt[3]{1}$? But thats $\omega$ for me... I dont see 7 subfields of degree 2.

Comment: Is it possible to write a small code (in some CAS like GAP or MAGMA) to demonstrate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finishing this exercise without a CAS would really help you to learn the Galois correspondence.  Here are the steps:

Step 1. Write down all roots of $f(x)$ explicitly: $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_5 = \ldots$

Step 2. You have to make the Galois group explicit too:  For each of the generators of the group, write down explicitly how it acts on $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_5$.

Step 3. Do one example, say the subfield $\mathbb{Q}(i, \omega)$.  It is invariant under which elements of $G$?  Note: since this field itself is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$, it means that the subgroup you will find must be a normal subgroup of $G$.

Step 4. Now start enumerating all subgroups and corresponding subfields.

Re: your question on $\sqrt{3}$,  that's an element of the subfield in Step 3.
Also: elements of order 2 do not correspond to subfields of degree 2!  They correspond to subfields of index 2 (i.e. degree 6). Remember that Galois correspondence is inclusion-reversing. So the 7 elements of order 2 give you 7 subfields of degree 6

Try to do Steps 1-4, let me know if you get stuck, and if so, where.

Comment: Thanks for the step-wise explanation (and sorry for the delay!)

I was able to do it without any CAS!!! :-)

Comment: About $\sqrt{3}$, it was my bad that I had not done the explicit calculations. Now I understand...